One object becoming black in render view
i'm following a tutorial and i just have to render it but the headboard of the bed is black in render view. Another weird thing is that in render view the top part is black and when rendering, the front part is black instead. What could be causing this?



Hello maybe it's z-fighting effect (faces overlapping)? Check the topology of your bed...
